# Symfony, twig forms, submitting through html form action path

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I was wondering is there a way I can submit into the database by using a path that will link to an action in a controller? I have my form in my shoe.html.twig template:

```
{ % if shoe is defined % }
<form action="{{ path('update_shoe', { 'shoeid' : shoe.id }) }}" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="color" value="{{shoe.color}}"><br />
   <input type="text" name="brand" value="{{shoe.brand}}"><br />
   <input type="text" name="heel" value="{{shoe.heel}}"><br />
   <button type="submit" name="submit">Update</button>
</form>
{ % endif % }
```

And the path goes to the controller in this way:

```
/**
* @Route("/updateshoes/{shoe_id}", name="update_shoe")
* @Method("PUT")
* @Template()
*/
public function updateShoeAction($shoeid) {
      //find the shoe by its id
      //update into database
}
```

Comment: Yes, best practices would be to use the [form component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) but you are on the right track. Although you set your route's method to "PUT" while your form is set to "POST".

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are on the right track but the only problem with your code is the definition of your route.

Instead of

```
/**
 * @Method("PUT")
 */
```

It should be

```
/**
 * @Method("POST")
 */
```

Because your form is going to POST to the specified URL.

Otherwise, I'd advise you to use the [form component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) because it will provide you with some nice tools like form validation and entity associations among other things.

Comment: Should I be using Post when I want to update into my database? Symfony's CRUD system used "PUT" so I was confused. I'm pretty new to Symfony and PHP.

Comment: you can use `post` or `put` method. you need to read more about `Restful` To knows when and where use `get`,`post`,`put`,`delete` methods http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer